# Defensive database programming- robust code with T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, defensive-programming

In the application development there is a concept of defensive programming. How to implement defensive programming techniques and writing robust code using Transact-SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Simple Talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/basic-defensive-database-programming-techniques/)...
- ...[books](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/book-review-defensive-database-programming-with-sql-server/)
- [SQL Server Central](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=defensive+TSQL)
- [Alexander Kuznetsov](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/tags/Defensive+programming/default.aspx) (who is SO user [AlexKuznetsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108977/alexkuznetsov))

More generally

- Understand [TRY..CATCH and error handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html)
- Datatype safety (no number compare against nvarchar for example)
- Understand transactions
- Consider stored procedures
- **Understand SQL injection**

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Scott said:

- Use TRY / CATCH which is now supported in SQL Server
- Validate the parameters of your procedures and use RAISERROR when things don't pass
- Use transactions (carefully)

Comment: care to give us some details on the _carefully_ aspect of transactions?

Comment: By carefully, I mean don't simply wrap an entire procedure in begin transaction ... commit transaction. Think about what needs to be transactional handle it accordingly

Comment: @Rafael Belliard: start late, finish early. never nest. SET XACT_ABORT ON

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS()
```

is something that should be used a lot more often in T-SQL I think. A lot of times when developers write SQL code they don't think in terms of exceptions and faults as they do when writing regular code.

Comment: Don't be afraid of RAISEERROR either if you are given invalid input for instance. This can be used like a ArgumentException in managed code to bubble issues back to the caller rather than just breaking or returning corrupt results.

Answer (score 1):

To consider the psychological angle to your question, you may find [DBA Survival Skills – Think Defensively](http://www.johnsansom.com/index.php/2010/04/dba-survival-skills-think-defensively/) to be interesting reading.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what all the others said, enforce data integrity in the database!